# Ansible update variables for module execution during loop

Tags: loops, ansible

I need to use ansible to do the following job:
 1. send a Http Post reuqest to a WebApi 
 2. check wheter the response meet requirement, otherwise extract some data from the response
 3. send another Http Post request with body filled with the data got in step 2
 4. loop step 1 to step 3 until the response meet requirement

My code is as the following, but it did not work.
 The `finished_res` seems to be undefined forever inside `uri` module.
 what I mean is that the variable `finished_res` inside the `uri` module seems to never change because I keep receiving the same request body in server. However, the `finished_res` outside the loop works, I could see the debug message.

```
- hosts: all
  remote_user: ubuntu
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    default_job_list: "xxx,yyy,zzz,aaa,bbb"

  tasks:
    - name: test is jobs finish
      uri: 
        url: "{{ API_URL }}"
        method: POST
        body: "{% if finished_res is defined %}{{ finished_res.json.remainingJobs }}{% else %}{{ default_job_list }}{% endif %}"
        return_content: yes
      register: finished_res
      changed_when: True
      until: finished_res is defined and finished_res.json is defined and finished_res.json.status is defined and finished_res.json.status != "FALSE"

    - set_fact: 
        RES: "{{ finished_res }}"

    - debug: msg="{{ RES }}"
```

Could anybody help me ? Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

At last, I solved the problem in another way : create a new ansible module